# Function image_send_to_editor returns emty title tag

Tags: functions, uploads, media

I am using the following code to wrap my images with figure when i send the images to the editor.

```
// Wrap the inserted image html with <figure>
    function html_insert_image( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) {
      $src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size, false );
      $html = "<figure id=\"post-$id media-$id\" class=\"align-$align\">";
      if ( $url ) {
      $html .= "<a href=\"$url\" class=\"image-link\"><img src=\"$src[0]\" title=\"$title\" alt=\"$alt\" /></a>";
  } else {
      $html .= "<img src=\"$src[0]\" title=\"$title\" alt=\"$alt\" />";
  }
  if ( $caption ) {
      $html .= "<p class='wp-caption-text'>$caption</p>";
  }
      $html .= "</figure>";
      return $html;
  }
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

But the title tag returns empty like `title=""`any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected, `title` is no longer used. [Have a look at where the function is called in source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php#L2668) that eventually fires that filter:

```
$title = ''; // We no longer insert title tags into <img> tags, as they are redundant.
```